# c++ using declaration and function overload

Tags: c++

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 
  3 namespace primerlib {
  4     void compute() { std::cout << "primerlib::print()" << std:: endl; }
  5     void compute(const void *p) { std::cout << "primerlib::print(const void *p)" << std:: endl; }
  6 }
  7 
  8 //using primerlib::compute;
  9 //using namespace primerlib;
 10 void compute(int a) { std::cout << "::compute(int)" << std:: endl; }
 11 void compute(double d, double dd=3.4) { std::cout << "primerlib::compute(d, d)" << std:: endl; }
 12 void compute(char* p, char* p1 = 0) { std::cout << "primerlib::compute(char*, char*)" << std:: endl; }
 13 
 14 int main(void)
 15 {
 16     using primerlib::compute;
 17     //using namespace primerlib;
 18     compute(0);
 19     return 0;
 20 }
```

output:

`primerlib::print(const void *p)`

my question is why it didn't call the global compute(int) one ? If I use using directive in line 17 and it will call the compute(int) one. Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: This demonstrates why you shouldn't use function overloading in that way. Don't give every function in your program the same name just because you _can!_

Comment: Anyway, `using` does not always refer to namespaces; it can also refer to individual functions. That's what this program does. It's been told to use the `compute` function in the `primerlib` namespace. I'm not sure I can explain why it behaves differently when you uncomment line 17 though. `0` is still a const void pointer.

Comment: It's just a sample code to understand namespace, using declaration/directive, and function overload.

Comment: Are you confused as to how a `void(const void*)` can be called with `0`? `0` represents a null pointer.

Comment: No, I'm confused why not call the global compute(int) one.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `using namespace X` and `using X::Y` work differently. When you use `using namespace X`, everything that is in that namespace is considered during the name lookup. Consider the following example:

```
namespace A
{
    void foo(int){}
}

namespace B
{
    void foo(int){}
}

using namespace A;
using namespace B;

int main()
{
    foo(1);
}
```

Here, both `A` and `B` members will be considered during the name lookup, and you will have the `call of overloaded foo(int) is ambiguous` error, because the compiler fails to decide which of the two functions to use, since they are identical. The `using X::Y` syntax is meant to solve this problem. When you use it, you tell the compiler to only use the `Y` found in `X` namespace, without considering anything else. Let's add it to the above example:

```
namespace A
{
    void foo(int){}
}

namespace B
{
    void foo(int){}
}

using namespace A;
using namespace B;


int main()
{
    using A::foo;  
    foo(1);
}
```

Here we tell the compiler to use the instance of `foo` found in the `A` namespace, and ignore any other `foo`s that are in scope. So, in your example you are telling the compiler to only use `primerlib::compute`, and you will have to use `::compute()` if you want to to access the functions from the global scope, and call the `compute(int)`.

Comment: "When you use `using namespace X`,"everything in that namespace is added to the nearest scope enclosing both `X` and the current scope. The names are not added to the current scope, which is what `using X::thing` does.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, sorry, that's just bad phrasing. I was meaning to say that they are considered during the name lookup. I'll rephrase that.

Answer (score 1):

> using primerlib::compute;

this is a `using` declaration. When you use it, it is as if a name is declared at the location of using declaration. You can bring back global `foo` by adding `using ::foo;` (or calling it with global scope `::foo(0);` and you will see `::compute(int)` in output.

The fact that in your example compiler is not finding global `foo` declaration, is because this is how name lookup works - it searches enclosing scopes and stopes once a name was found.

For more reference on using declaration see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations

[edit]

I misunderstood your question, in line 17 you have 'using directive', it behaves differently from `using declaration`, it does not introduce name in nearest enclosing declarative region (in your case its main function), but adds names to nearest enclosing namespace - in this cast it is global namespace. For more reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives:

> Using-directives are allowed only in namespace scope and in block scope. From the point of view of unqualified name lookup of any name after a using-directive and until the end of the scope in which it appears, ***every name from namespace-name is visible as if it were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace*** which contains both the using-directive and namespace-name.
>
> ***Using-directive does not add any names to the declarative region in which it appears*** (unlike the using-declaration), and thus does not prevent identical names from being declared.

Comment: I mean the global overloads are also visible for main, why those global overloads are not considered as candidates? Also, it will call the global one if I use line 17.

Comment: @ponypaver Because the global overload is shadowed by the `using`. `using ns::symbol` more or less says "*pull `symbol` into local scope*". And since `compute()` is now found in the local scope, global scope is no longer even searched in.

Comment: @ponypaver `I mean the global overloads are also visible for main,` name lookup already found name declared locally in function scope so it does not look into global scope, thats why calling compute(0.1); will generate error. There is a way around it with ADL (Argument Dependant Lookup), if you have at global scope : `class X{}; void compute(X n){}`, and you call it in main : `compute(X());` then it will still be found even if you have `using primerlib::compute;`;

Answer (score 0):

With the actual using declaration, you are saying that compute is a name that refers only to function defined in namespace primerlib: in fact if you try to call the compute function that accepts a double, you get an error of no matching function.
With the commented using declaration, you give all compute functions the "same importance": to refer to global ones, you have to use the "::" namespace resolution directive, to refer to primer's namespace ones, you have to use the "primerlib::" namespace resolution directive.

Comment: what's the difference between: using primerlib::compute and using namespace primerlib? For me, I think the global overload functions are also visible for the main.

Answer (score 0):

`using directive` and `using declaration` hehaviours differently in this case.

7.3.4$2 Using directive [namespace.udir]: (bold by me)

> A using-directive specifies that the names in the nominated namespace
>   can be used in the scope in which the using-directive appears after
>   the using-directive. During unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), the names
>   appear as if they were declared in the **nearest enclosing namespace**
>   which contains both the using-directive and the nominated namespace. [
>   Note: In this context, “contains” means “contains directly or
>   indirectly”. —end note ]

In this case, the nearest enclosing namespace is the global namaspace, the functions of namespace `primerlib` appear in the same namespace with other global functions, so after the overloading resolution `::compute(int)` was called.

7.3.3$1 The using declaration [namespace.udecl]:

> A using-declaration introduces a name into the declarative region in
>   which the using-declaration appears.

The functions of namespace `primerlib` will be introduced into the `main` function scope, and they will be selected at the stage of name lookup with high precedence, and then name lookup will stop. The global functions will not be considered for overloading resolution, so `primerlib::compute(const void *p)` was called.

BTW:If you move `using primerlib::compute;` out of the `main` function, you will get same result as using `using namespace primerlib;` in `main` function.

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/JJQJ95524)

Comment: then why the global overloads are not selected as the call candidates since they are visible for main?

Comment: @ponypaver At the stage of name lookup, if compiler can find the name (`compute` in this case) at current scope, the name loopup will stop. That means the global version functions will not be considered for overloading resolution. It is a kind of name hiding.

Comment: You have to keep reading after "nearest enclosing namespace." The relevant namespace is not simply the enclosing one.