# Function hiding and using-declaration in C++

Tags: c++, scope, namespaces

My confusion comes from "C++ Primer 5th edition" section 13.3, page 518.

> Very careful readers may wonder why the `using` declaration inside `swap` does not hide the declarations for the `HasPtr` version of `swap`.

I tried to read its reference but still did not understand why. Could anyone explain it a little bit please? Thanks. Here is the code sample of the question.

Assume class `Foo` has a member named `h`, which has type `HasPtr`.

```
void swap(HasPtr &lhs, HasPtr &rhs)
{...}

void swap(Foo &lhs, Foo &rhs)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs.h, rhs.h);
}
```

Why `swap` for `HasPtr` is not hidden which seems to be declared in outer scope while `using std::swap` is in the inner scope? Thanks.

Comment: because `using` has no effect on that

Answer (score 10):

Because `using std::swap;` does not mean "henceforth, every 'swap' should use `std::swap`", but "bring all overloads of `swap` from `std` into the current scope".

In this case, the effect is the same as if you had written `using namespace std;` inside the function.

Comment: I understand the `using` declaration introduces the `swap` in `std`, but if it works similar to normal function declaration, it should hide the names from outer space, not just introduces the names in `std`. Btw, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265938/c-using-declaration-and-function-overload says `using`declaration and directive are different, which makes me confused. Thanks.

Comment: And the declaration and the directive *are* different but as I wrote, in *this case* the effect is the same.

Comment: Thanks. If `f` were variables, then it should be hidden, right? Declarations of variable and function have different hiding policies?

Comment: Actually I just tried, in your example, f in the outer space will be hidden.

Comment: @Sean Yeah, you're right. Sorry. I shouldn't do this with a fever.

Answer (score 8):

The *using-declaration* `using std::swap` does not hide the functions you have declared to swap `HasPtr` and `Foo`. It brings the name `swap` form the `std` namespace to the declarative region. With that, `std::swap` can take part in overload resolution.

From the C++11 Standard:

> **7.3.3 The using declaration**
>
> 1 A *using-declaration* introduces a name into the declarative region in which the using-declaration appears.
>
> *using-declaration:*
>
> `using typename`<sub>*opt*</sub> *nested-name-specifier unqualified-id ;*
>      `using ::` *unqualified-id ;*
>
> The member name specified in a *using-declaration* is declared in the declarative region in which the *using-declaration* appears. [ *Note:* Only the specified name is so declared; specifying an enumeration name in a *using-declaration* does not declare its enumerators in the *using-declaration*’s declarative region. *—end note* ] If a *using-declaration* names a constructor (3.4.3.1), it implicitly declares a set of constructors in the class in which the *using-declaration* appears (12.9); otherwise the name specified in a *using-declaration* is a synonym for the name of some entity declared elsewhere.

In your case, you have:

```
void swap(Foo &lhs, Foo &rhs)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs.h, rhs.h);
}
```

The `using std::swap;` declaration introduces the name `swap` from the `std` namespace into the declarative region, which is the body of the `swap(Foo&, Foo&)` function. The name `swap` from the global namespace is still accessible in the body of the function.

If what you posted is the entirety of the function, then you don't need the `using std::swap` declaration. You could get by with just:

```
void swap(Foo &lhs, Foo &rhs)
{
    swap(lhs.h, rhs.h);
}
```

since `swap(HasPtr &lhs, HasPtr &rhs)` is visible from the function.

Now, take a look at the example below.

```
struct Bar {};

void swap(Bar& lhs, Bar& rhs)
{
}

struct Foo
{
   int a;
   Bar b;
};

void swap(Foo& lhs, Foo& rhs)
{
   swap(lhs.a, rhs.a);  // A problem
   swap(lhs.b, rhs.b);
}
```

The line marked `A problem` is a problem since there is no function named `swap` that can work with  two objects of type`int&` as argument. You can fix that using one of the following methods:

1. Use `std::swap` explicitly.

   ```
   void swap(Foo& lhs, Foo& rhs)
   {
      std::swap(lhs.a, rhs.a);
      swap(lhs.b, rhs.b);
   }
   ```
2. Introduce `std::swap` in the function.

   ```
   void swap(Foo& lhs, Foo& rhs)
   {
      using std::swap;
      swap(lhs.a, rhs.a);
      swap(lhs.b, rhs.b);
   }
   ```

Comment: "A using-declaration does not hide anything" - it does hide the `swap` declared in the global namespace for simple unqualified lookup in this case. However, that `swap` is still found by ADL, because the associated namespace of `HasPtr` is the global namespace. If the global `swap` had parameters of, say, `int&` and you called it with arguments of type `int` (which have no associated namespace, so ADL doesn't find anything), you'd see the hiding introduced by the using declaration (the `std` overload will be called, even though the global overload is a better match).

Comment: @bogdan, thanks for pointing out the error. I agree with everything in your comment.

Comment: @bogdan I like your answer but since it is a comment instead of an answer, so... I have voted for you. I tried on VS 2015, and using-declaration does hide the function, it is the argument `HasPtr` saves the world. `HasPtr` is defined in the global namespace and so the global namespace is searched and the `swap` with `HasPtr` is found.

Comment: "the name swap from the global namespace is still accessible in the body of the function."-- Why this is true? I read from c++ primer (5th, 6.4.1) that "If we declare a name in an inner scope, that name hides uses of that name declared in an outer scope. **Names do not overload across scopes.**"

Comment: @ivy, that's true but you can still bring the names from the outer scope to the inner scope for overload resolution. See https://ideone.com/tTtUsG.

Comment: @RSahu In you example, `using outer::foo` does not hide `void foo(double)`, because `void foo(double)` is not in the outer scope of  the scope in which `using outer::foo` resides. They are in the same scope.

Comment: @ivy, it's the other way around. `inner::foo` will hide `outer::foo`. By using `using outer::foo`, we are making both of them visible in `inner`.

Answer (score 0):

Effective C++ Third Edition by Scott Meyers (Item 24)

> When compilers see the call to swap, they search for the right swap to
>   invoke. C++’s name lookup rules ensure that this will find any
>   T-specific swap at global scope or in the same namespace as the type
>   T.

In this case and in the second block of code, compilers look for a HasPtr swap and if they don't find it they fall back on the general version in std.

Answer (score 0):

The using declaration means to consider all of the std::swap overloads as if they were defined in the same namespace as the function. Since the using declaration appears in a function body, this only has an effect temporarily: within that scope.

It is identical in effect to the following:

```
void swap(HasPtr &lhs, HasPtr &rhs)
{...}

void swap(int &lhs, int &rhs) { std::swap(lhs, rhs); }
void swap(char &lhs, char &rhs) { std::swap(lhs, rhs); }
// etc. for other std::swap overloads of common types

void swap(Foo &lhs, Foo &rhs)
{
    swap(lhs.h, rhs.h);
    // the other overloads of swap go out of scope here.
}
```

The regular rules of overloading ensure that the first swap is the one that gets called. This is in contrast to declaring a local variable named "swap", which *would* hide the first overload.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, The `swap` for HasPtr is hidden while `using std::swap` in the inner scope, but in this case the `std::swap` in the inner scope is the same as the `swap` for HasPtr in the outer scope.