# Why using std::swap does not hide other swap functions in the outer scope

Tags: c++, namespaces, hide, overloading, swap

In C++ Primer 5th, Section 13.3:

> Very careful readers may wonder why the using declaration inside swap does not hide the declaration for the HasPtr version of swap (6.4.1). We'll explain the reasons for why this code works in 18.2.3.

Here is the sample code:

```
void swap(HasPtr &lhs, HasPtr &rhs)
{...}

void swap(Foo &lhs, Foo &rhs)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs.h, rhs.h);
}
```

Indeed, I am wondering why `using std::swap` will not hide `void swap(HasPtr &lhs, HasPtr &rhs)` within the scope of `void swap(Foo &lhs, Foo &rhs)`? Instead, it seems that the `std::swap` functions and `void swap(HasPtr &lhs, HasPtr &rhs)` are being overloaded.

This is in contrary to the following statement (quoted from C++ Primer 5th, Section 6.4.1):

> If we declare a name in an inner scope, that name hides uses of that name declared in an outer scope. Names do not overload across scopes.

Let us consider the following example:

```
#include<iostream>
namespace a{
    void f(int a){  std::cout<< "a::f(int)";}
}
void f(double a){ std::cout<< "f(double)";}

int main(){
  using a::f;
    f(1.11);
}
```

In this case, when we use `using a::f`, it hides the function `void f(double a)` in the outer scope. Therefore, we get the following output

```
a::f(int)
```

which implies that the function `void f(int a)` is being used here, although `void f(double a)` would've been a better match (but it is hidden).

To conclude, it seems that
(1)`using std::swap` **overloads** all `swap` functions in the outer scope in the first case
(2)  `using a::f` **hides** all `f` functions in the outer scope in the second case

My question is, why such difference?

By the way, this is related to [Function hiding and using-declaration in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388431), all the answers therein claimed that all swaps function are overload without explaining why, so I am opening another question here.

Comment: Why not read section 18.2.3 of the book?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on the exact behaviour, but, if I'm right, `using std::swap` does hide other functions. However, there's something called Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL) which has priority. Basically, when you write `swap(lhs.h, rhs.h)`, the compiler first looks for the function `swap` according to the rules of ADL (basically, look in the namespace where the type is defined for a function of the name `swap` with the type as one of the arguments), then, if it can't find such a `swap`, it calls the `swap` function at the call site, which is `std::swap` because of the `using std::swap`

Comment: a::f(int)  you are asking  where to look for name

Comment: Try this #include<iostream>
namespace a{
    void f(char a){  std::cout<< "a::f(char)";}
}
void f(double a){ std::cout<< "f(double)";}

int main(){
  using a::f;
    f('a');
}

Comment: @Justin, Thanks! As a followup question, ADL is the reason why we **DO NOT** need to declare `using std::operator>>`, `using std::move`, and `using std::forward` (as explained in Section 18.2.3). Yer here the author emphasized that we **MUST** declare `using std::swap`. Why is so?

Comment: @ivy The `using std::swap` presents a fallback in case there is no ADL `swap` function. Otherwise, the code wouldn't know how to perform a `swap` operation if there was no ADL swap defined for the type. For stream operators, there's no fallback. Do note that it's good practice to use `std::move` and `std::forward` fully-qualified.

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
using a::f;
```

you are bringing the declaration of `a::f` to the scope of the declarative region. The *declarative region* part is key here.

In your case, it is the declarative region of `main`. There are no other declarations of `f` in `main`. Hence, `f` resolves to `a::f`.

To make both `a::f` and the global `f` to be visible from main, use:

```
using a::f;
void f(double a){ std::cout<< "f(double)";}
```

If you do that, both `a::f` and the global `f` become available to `main`.

See it working at https://ideone.com/ySvGlP.